# call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, second array member is not valid method in

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating my own theme in WordPress, trying to link external stylesheet.

My code is:

```
call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int)$the_['accepted_args'] ) );
```

but it returns the error:

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   second array member is not valid method in

I've got no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What that error means is that `$the_['function']` is an array, and so PHP is attempting to interpret `$the_['function'][0]` as an object and `$the_['function'][1]` as a method of that object, and a method of that name does not exist on the object. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) on callbacks:

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.

So you need to check the contents of `$the_['function']` to figure out what exactly is in there and how you should be calling `call_user_func_array()`.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to include an external stylesheet is as follows:

```
function enqueue_custom_styles() {

    /*Enqueue The Styles*/
    wp_enqueue_style( 'themename', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_styles' );
```